# Res.render, possible to create a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

im using this structure of mean stack: https://github.com/meanjs/mean

Currently im using `res.render` as follows:

```
res.render('modules/core/server/views/index', {
  user: safeUserObject,
});
```

is it possible to assign it to a angularjs controller?

I dont know how to do it with my current structure.

Update:

I managed to get controller to work, but i cant get the data from it?
i also need the headcontroller to be the root scope.

code:

```
  function HeaderController($scope, $state, Authentication, menuService) {
var vm = this;

vm.accountMenu = menuService.getMenu('account').items[0];
vm.authentication = Authentication;

vm.datatest = 200000;
$scope.datatest = 200001;
console.log("loaded , maybe possible4?");
```

}

the console.log is executed, but i cant find any of the values.

client :

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController">

<font style="color:white;">{{ vm.datatest }} {{ datatest }} {{ datatest }}</font>

</div>
```

some debug :

[image]

Comment: Your template should define the controller. `ng-controller` in your HTML, or use angular routing to define which controller maps to the template

Comment: i had that in mind @SterlingArcher , but i dont know how im supposed to do that with the structure im using ( that i linked to)

Comment: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/users/client/config/users-admin.client.routes.js check this page out, this is where he's configuring the angular routing

Comment: You can assign the angular controller normally, using `ng-controller`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher i did look at that, but that is for the ui-view. I need a controller assigned to the main layout that always is rendered too.

Comment: So, again, use `ng-controller` to define it

Comment: updated the thread @SterlingArcher having trouble to recieve it.

Comment: do you know how to assign a controller ?  check here http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: tes i do @DeendayalGarg, Updated the answer now.

Comment: why are you doing `ng-class="HeaderController"`? it should be `ng-controller="HeaderController"`

Comment: sorry @DeendayalGarg was a typo in the topic. it is ng-controller on my tests. updated.

Comment: Can you try `ng-controller="HeaderController as vm"` and check if it is working?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the controllerAs syntax if you're going to assign this to vm.

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController as vm">
    <span>{{vm.data}}</span>
</div>
```

To share data between parent controller and children, either use a service/factory or assign data to $rootScope. Example using $rootScope:

```
//parent controller
function HeaderController ($rootScope) {
    var vm  = this;
    $rootScope.data = 'This is a string';
    //inject $rootScope into child controllers to get or set $rootScope.data
}

//child controller
function ChildController ($rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = $rootScope.data;
}
```

The preferred way in most cases is to use a service or factory:

```
//parent controller
function HeaderController (factory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = 'This is a string';
    factory.set(vm.data);
    //set data in factory from parent controller 
}

//child controller
function ChildController (factory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = factory.get();
    //get data from factory set in child controller
}

//basic example factory
function factory () {
    var data;
    var factory = {
        get: get,
        set: set
    }
    return factory;

    function get () { return data; }
    function set (item) { data = item; }
}
```

To render main template and partial use $routeProvider in config block:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'main' })
    .when('/:template, {
        templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
            return urlattr.template;
        }
    });
});
```

Define routes in express:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res ,next) {
    res.render('main')
})

router.get('/:template', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render(req.params.template)
})
```

This will render the main template when a request is made to the root. When changing routes in angular using $location.path('index') for example, a request is made to the '/:template' route in express and it will look for a template named 'index in your views folder and render as a partial, while leaving the 'main' template rendered.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: i cant get the result: http://prntscr.com/ch9w0i

<font style="color:white;"> {{ vm.datatest }} </font> wont work. according to the example above.

Comment: Make sure your font tag is nested under the div with the controller definition.

Comment: IT is @Zofskeez The controller is in The Body.